# Wordpress how to show all posts in the index page and exclude sticky posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

Since Wordpress sticky posts feature allow the post checked as sticky in post publish panel to be placed at the top of the front page of posts.

I want to  show all posts in index without sticky posts:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
?>
    <div class="row my-4">
    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            /**
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', 'index' ); // Post format: content-index.php
        endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
<?php
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: what's your problem? Code seems good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pre_get_posts` action hook to manipulate the query. Since you need to modify the query on your `index.php`, the you could use the `is_home` conditional check.

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'your_theme_no_sticky_posts_query');

function your_theme_no_sticky_posts_query($query)
{
  if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', get_option('sticky_posts'));
  }
}
```

Code goes into the `functions.php` of your active theme.